# Custom ComboBox throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, combobox

My custom ComboBox source is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IHWinUtility
{
    public class IHComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        private IHComboBoxItems _ihComboBoxItems;

        public IHComboBox()
        {
            this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            _ihComboBoxItems = new IHComboBoxItems(this);
        }

        new public IHComboBoxItems Items
        {
            get { return _ihComboBoxItems; }
            set { _ihComboBoxItems = (IHComboBoxItems)value; }
        }

        new public string SelectedValue
        {
            get { return this.SelectedItem == null ? "" : ((IHComboBoxItem)this.SelectedItem).Value.ToString(); }
        }
    }


    public class IHComboBoxItems : ComboBox.ObjectCollection
    {
        public IHComboBox _ihComboBox;

        public IHComboBoxItems(IHComboBox owner) : base(owner)
        {
            _ihComboBox = owner;
        }

        public int Add(string Text, object Value)
        {
            int _retValue = 0;

            IHComboBoxItem _item = new IHComboBoxItem();
            _item.Text = Text;
            _item.Value = Value;
            _ihComboBox.Items.Add(_item);

            _retValue = _ihComboBox.Items.Count;

            return _retValue;
        }

        new public void Insert(int index, object item)
        {

        }
    }


    public class IHComboBoxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
}
```

and I added some data to that combobox as below:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ihComboBox1.Items.Add("Text1", "Value1");
    }
```

It worked fine.
I can see Text1 binded to my Combobox.
But the problem is when I change selectedItem by clicking the arrow in Combobox, it throws me the errors below:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled Message="InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index
   at: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at: System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.get_SelectedItem()
   at: System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.get_Text()
   at: System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at: System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

In selected value you are trying to force a value. But that value is not in collection.

Answer (score 0):

When your code call IHComboBoxItems::Add method, new object will be added to IHComboBox._ihComboBoxItems collection, with is different from original ComboBox.Items collection. Original ComboBox.Items will be empty.

ComboBox.get_Text is using ComboBox.Items property to get SelectedItem by current SelectedIndex.

Dropdown list using reflection to enumerate Items collection, with is mapped to new IHComboBoxItems.Items property (will be not empty after call Add), and allow user to select nonzero SelectedIndex, but original ComboBoxItems.Items will stay empty. When internal ComboBox code trying to load Text it call original ComboBox.Items (stay empty) with nonzero SelectedIndex and cause Exception.

Try to create and use wrapper over the ObjectCollection istead of create new ObjectCollection instance. **But in wrapper code you must check link to ObjectCollection instance every time before use it** (or you will get ArgumentOutOfRangeException), because ComboBox code can recreate it and not allow to override create ObjectCollection instance contruction.

Code example:

```
public abstract class TypedComboBox<T> : ComboBox
{
    public TypedComboBox()
    {
        _objectCollectionProxy = new TypedObjectCollectionProxy<T>(this);
    }

    private TypedObjectCollectionProxy<T> _objectCollectionProxy;

    public ObjectCollection ObjectCollectionCollection
    {
        get { return base.Items; }
    }

    public class TypedObjectCollectionProxy<ItemType> : IList, IList<ItemType>, ICollection, ICollection<ItemType>, IEnumerable, IEnumerable<ItemType>
    {
        public ObjectCollection _objectCollection;
        private TypedComboBox<T> _owner;

        public TypedObjectCollectionProxy(TypedComboBox<T> owner)
        {
            this._owner = owner;
            this._objectCollection = owner.ObjectCollectionCollection;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the number of items in the collection</summary>
        public int Count { get { return _objectCollection.Count; } }
        /// <summary>Gets a value indicating whether this collection can be modified</summary>
        public bool IsReadOnly { get { return _objectCollection.IsReadOnly; } }

        /// <summary>Retrieves the item at the specified index within the collection</summary>
        /// <param name="index">The index of the item in the collection to retrieve</param>
        /// <returns>An object representing the item located at the specified index within the collection</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">The index was less than zero.-or- The index was greater than the count of
        ///                                                          items in the collection.</exception>
        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public virtual ItemType this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                CheckItems();
                return (ItemType)_objectCollection[index];
            }
            set
            {
                CheckItems();
                _objectCollection[index] = value;
            }
        }

        public void CheckItems()
        {
            if (this._objectCollection != _owner.ObjectCollectionCollection)
                this._objectCollection = _owner.ObjectCollectionCollection;
        }

        /// <summary>Adds an item to the list of items for a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox</summary>
        /// <param name="item">An object representing the item to add to the collection</param>
        /// <returns>The zero-based index of the item in the collection</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">The item parameter was null</exception>
        public int Add(ItemType item)
        {
            CheckItems();
            return _objectCollection.Add(item);
        }

        /// <summary>Adds an array of items to the list of items for a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox</summary>
        /// <param name="items">An array of objects to add to the list</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">An item in the items parameter was null</exception>
        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<ItemType> items)
        {
            CheckItems();
            _objectCollection.AddRange(items.Cast<object>().ToArray());
        }

        /// <summary>Removes all items from the System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox</summary>
        public void Clear()
        {
            CheckItems();
            _objectCollection.Clear();
        }

        /// <summary>Determines if the specified item is located within the collection</summary>
        /// <param name="value">An object representing the item to locate in the collection</param>
        /// <returns>true if the item is located within the collection; otherwise, false</returns>
        public bool Contains(ItemType value)
        {
            CheckItems();
            return _objectCollection.Contains(value);
        }

        /// <summary>Copies the entire collection into an existing array of objects at a specified location within the array</summary>
        /// <param name="destination">The object array to copy the collection to</param>
        /// <param name="arrayIndex">The location in the destination array to copy the collection to</param>
        public void CopyTo(object[] destination, int arrayIndex)
        {
            CheckItems();
            _objectCollection.CopyTo(destination, arrayIndex);
        }

        /// <summary>Returns an enumerator that can be used to iterate through the item collection</summary>
        /// <returns>An System.Collections.IEnumerator that represents the item collection</returns>
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            CheckItems();
            return _objectCollection.GetEnumerator();
        }

        /// <summary>Retrieves the index within the collection of the specified item</summary>
        /// <param name="value">An object representing the item to locate in the collection</param>
        /// <returns>The zero-based index where the item is located within the collection; otherwise, -1</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">The value parameter was null</exception>
        public int IndexOf(ItemType value)
        {
            CheckItems();
            return _objectCollection.IndexOf(value);
        }

        /// <summary>Inserts an item into the collection at the specified index</summary>
        /// <param name="index">The zero-based index location where the item is inserted</param>
        /// <param name="item">An object representing the item to insert</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">The item was null</exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">The index was less than zero.-or- The index was greater than the count of items in the collection</exception>
        public void Insert(int index, ItemType item)
        {
            CheckItems();
            _objectCollection.Insert(index, item);
        }

        /// <summary>Removes the specified item from the System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox</summary>
        /// <param name="value">The System.Object to remove from the list</param>
        public bool Remove(ItemType value)
        {
            int kIndex = IndexOf(value);
            if (kIndex >= 0)
            {
                CheckItems();
                _objectCollection.RemoveAt(kIndex);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>Removes an item from the System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox at the specified index</summary>
        /// <param name="index">The index of the item to remove</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">The value parameter was less than zero.-or- The value parameter was greater than or equal to the count of items in the collection</exception>
        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            CheckItems();
            _objectCollection.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        #region IList Members

        int IList.Add(object value)
        {
            return this.Add((ItemType)value);
        }

        void IList.Clear()
        {
            this.Clear();
        }

        bool IList.Contains(object value)
        {
            return this.Contains((ItemType)value);
        }

        int IList.IndexOf(object value)
        {
            return this.IndexOf((ItemType)value);
        }

        void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
        {
            this.Insert(index, (ItemType)value);
        }

        bool IList.IsFixedSize
        {
            get
            {
                CheckItems();
                return (_objectCollection as IList).IsFixedSize;
            }
        }

        bool IList.IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return this.IsReadOnly; }
        }

        void IList.Remove(object value)
        {
            this.Remove((ItemType)value);
        }

        void IList.RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            this.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        object IList.this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return this[index];
            }
            set
            {
                this[index] = (ItemType)value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region ICollection Members

        void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
        {
            this.CopyTo((object[])array, index);
        }

        int ICollection.Count
        {
            get { return this.Count; }
        }

        bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
        {
            get
            {
                CheckItems();
                return (_objectCollection as ICollection).IsSynchronized;
            }
        }

        object ICollection.SyncRoot
        {
            get
            {
                CheckItems();
                return (_objectCollection as ICollection).SyncRoot;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<ItemType> Members

        IEnumerator<ItemType> IEnumerable<ItemType>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            CheckItems();
            return _objectCollection.Cast<ItemType>().GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region ICollection<ItemType> Members

        void ICollection<ItemType>.Add(ItemType item)
        {
            this.Add(item);
        }

        void ICollection<ItemType>.Clear()
        {
            this.Clear();
        }

        bool ICollection<ItemType>.Contains(ItemType item)
        {
            return this.Contains(item);
        }

        void ICollection<ItemType>.CopyTo(ItemType[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        int ICollection<ItemType>.Count
        {
            get { return this.Count; }
        }

        bool ICollection<ItemType>.IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return this.IsReadOnly; }
        }

        bool ICollection<ItemType>.Remove(ItemType item)
        {
            return this.Remove(item);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    /// <summary>Gets an object representing the collection of the items contained in this System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox</summary>
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public new TypedObjectCollectionProxy<T> Items
    {
        get { return _objectCollectionProxy; }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets currently selected item in the System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox</summary>
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public new T SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (T)base.SelectedItem; }
        set { base.SelectedItem = value; }
    }
}
```

It is my own abstract generic ComboBox.